# Can't get xbee-api OpenCloseConnectionsTest.java to work

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm currently using Netbeans on Windows 7, and I'm trying to run the the xbee-api's OpenCloseConnection test but keep getting connection still open errors.

I use XCTU to make sure I'm in API mode and I've updated the variable "device" to be the COM that the xbee is on...

What are some leads?  Below is the exception:

> Exception in thread "main" com.rapplogic.xbee.api.XBeeException   at
>   com.rapplogic.xbee.api.XBee.open(XBee.java:146)   at
>   VFART.Main.main(Main.java:82) Caused by: gnu.io.PortInUseException:
>   Unknown Application   at
>   gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.open(CommPortIdentifier.java:354)   at
>   com.rapplogic.xbee.RxTxSerialComm.openSerialPort(RxTxSerialComm.java:97)
>     at
>   com.rapplogic.xbee.RxTxSerialComm.openSerialPort(RxTxSerialComm.java:61)
>     at com.rapplogic.xbee.api.XBee.open(XBee.java:140)